# Как сохранить большой массив 14млн строк

Tags: php, динамические-массивы, обработка-данных

Есть скрипт. Генерирует массив комбинаций спортлото.
Мне нужно как то работать с данным массивом. `5` из `36` сохраняет и я могу с ним работать. А вот `6` из `49` не хватает ресурсов.
Как я могу сохранить результат для работы с массивом. Нужно удалить ненужные комбинации.

```
$masInit = range(1, 36);
$result = []; 
$combination = [];

function combinations($myArray, $choose) {
    global $result, $combination;

    $n = count($myArray);

    function inner ($start, $choose_, $arr, $n) {
        global $result, $combination;

        if ($choose_ == 0) {
            array_push($result,$combination);
        } else {
            for ($i = $start; $i <= $n - $choose_; ++$i) {
                array_push($combination, $arr[$i]);
                inner($i + 1, $choose_ - 1, $arr, $n);
                array_pop($combination);
            }
        }
    }

    inner(0, $choose, $myArray, $n);
    return $result;
}

$rm = combinations($masInit, 6);
unset($masInit);
$comb = [];

foreach ($rm as $v) {
    $n=implode(",", $v);
    //print_r ($n);
    array_push($comb, $n);
}

file_put_contents('5_36.txt', print_r($comb, true));
```

Comment: а чего вы с ними делаете то? вам точно их надо сохранять, и вообще в памяти всей кучей хранить?

Comment: Насколько часто это нужно делать ?

Comment: один раз сохранить. Нужно удалить ненужные комбинации.

Comment: Если я все правильно понял, то Вам нужно обрабатывать комбинации последовательно, то есть если сгенерированная комбинация устраиват, то в файл, если нет, то переходим к следующей затирая массив новыми значениями. Либо, вы можете обрабатывать ваши комбинации не по одному, а по-блочно. Например, сгенерировали 10, обработали, сохранили, отбросили и так далее.

Comment: Что такое "не нужные" комбинации, может их просто не создавать.